# Using ngClass on Custom Component in Angular 7

Tags: angular, components, ng-class

I have a custom component that I am trying to add an ".empty" class to based on a variable, but the class never gets added. Even if I simply change !myArray.length to true. Is this directive possible with a custom component? If not what would be a good workaround. Nesting another element before or after this tag is not an option for me.

```
<a-grid rows="true" class="a-grid" [ngClass]="{'empty': !myArray.length }">
```

Comment: Is the class in your global styles file or just on the component itself? If you view the page source can you see the class added to the HTML and it's just not loading the CSS, or is the class not added to the HTML element at all?

Comment: Its in my global file. No the class is never added to my HTML. The only way I was able to add it was by creating a variable that's value was set to 'empty' if my conditions are not meet. Then use interpolation {{ myVariable }} in the class property of the custom element. However this is not a good solution for my case as there is no good way to update this when the parent changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main question is:
 Is it possible to use [ngClass] with a custom component? 
The answer is yes. But sometimes it is tricky. 
For example see the below link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csprde?file=src/app/app.component.css

As you see, ngClass works perfectly with the custom component.
But just remove position:absolute; from empty and def class. ngClass works but the result is not as same as we expect.

When you use ngClass with the custom component, it's better to do not use class="". 
See ths example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3jdkra?file=src/app/app.component.html

As I said before, using ngClass is sometimes tricky. Can you create a simple project in stackblitz if it is not solved yet?

**Edit 1:**

I worked on your stackblitz project.
 [yourProject](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5cs3x?embed=1&file=src/app/some-component/some-component.component.html) One solution is to use class="{{myClass}}" instead of [ngClass].
So I changed the some-component.component.html to this: . Copy and paste in to your project:

```
<a-component 
   rows="true"

   class='{{myClass}}'

   [attr.data-itemIndex]="itemIndex"
 >I should be blue if empty is assigned</a-component>


  <button (click)="myClass='dropzone'" style="margin:10px;">dropzone 
  </button>

 <button (click)="myClass='dropzone 
 empty'"style="margin:10px;">dropzone 
 empty </button>
```

I added to buttons and you can change myClass variable to assign some classes to the component.
Do not forget to add define myClass as a string variable in your ts file:

```
myClass="dropzone empty";
```

So you can see result here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-56ybzr?file=src/app/a-component/a-component.component.ts

Comment: Here is a link to a scaled down version pretty close to how I have it set up: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5cs3x?embed=1&file=src/app/some-component/some-component.component.html

Comment: I found a solution and just edited my answer. Good Luck.

Comment: I have also come to a similar conclusion. I really don't like the fact I have to tuck CSS class names away in my JS code, but it sounds like that really is the best solution until I can rework my core code a bit. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `class.classname` as below:

```
<a-grid rows="true" class="a-grid" [class.empty]="!myArray.length">
```